# Want to achieve big O(n) by un-nesting these for loops. Tried this, but get TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json

```
import json

hrefs = list()

# open all workloads file as input
with open('json/allWorkloads.json') as workloads:
    workloads = json.load(workloads)

with open('/users/home/xbbpggp/illumioProject/json/updatedDuplicates.json') as dups:
    dups = json.load(dups)

# for dup in dups:
#     dupHref = dup["href"]
#     for workload in range(len(workloads)-1):
#         if workloads[workload]["href"] == dupHref:
#             del workloads[workload]

for dup in dups:
    hrefs.append(dup["href"])

for workload in range(len(workloads)-1):
    if workload["href"] in hrefs:
        del workloads[workload]

with open('json/noDupWorkloads.json', 'w') as f:  
    json.dump(workloads, f, indent=4)
```

This is my code at the moment. What is commented out, is my currently working script. However, when given tens of thousands of workloads, this takes an extremely long time to run due to big O(n^2). I tried to separate them out, and keep track of each dup href in a list, however I get error message for line 22:

```
if workload["href"] in hrefs:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
```

Any fixes to this, or alternatives to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Edit:

I tried first recommended change:

```
if workloads[workload]["href"] in hrefs:
```

However this now yields a new error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However someone in comments now brought to my attention that the `in` operator will still be O(n^2)...But at least its not nested like before? So would it still be somewhat better if I continue trying to fix this?

Comment: Do you have an example input for the two files?

Comment: Why did you change your `if` condition? Try `if workloads[workload]["href"] in hrefs`

Comment: as you are using workload as an iterable in the for loop (`workload in range`), the workload is an integer, and integers are not subscriptable. Try doing workloads[workload][href] in hrefs:

Comment: @FloLie Sensitive data in the inputs, however both input files are standard JSON files-- array of workload objects, in which "href" is the first key:value. Both files are structured in the same exact way.

Comment: FYI - this will still be `O(n^2)`. Using the `in` operator will, at worst, check every item in the list.

Comment: @SomeName and not_speshal-- I have tried that as well, but I get a new error: IndexError: list index out of range. I will add to an edit to show this.

Comment: @piticent123 hmm thats a good point, I did not notice that. However, does this mean if I can fix this, it would still be better ```O()``` than it was previously, when it was nested?

Comment: yes - in fact, according to [the documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), dictionaries are implemented as hash tables under the hood (ie, on average, `in` is `O(1)`), so by changing the list to a dictionary, you can achieve `O(n)` performance